# Django UUIDField - Make it shorter

Tags: django, django-models, uuid

Im using the django field like this:

```
import uuid   
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

A typical id would look like this:

```
6abbde08-99b1-42c7-8bd2-3ec92a4b67b9
```

Is it possible to make the id shorter, to something like **99b1** ?

Answer (score 4):

The point of a UUID field is that it is extremely unlikely that two uuids generated will collide. You can't store `99b1` in a `UUID` field, because it's not a UUID.

You could use a `CharField` with max length 4 as your primary key, but then you will be responsible for generating the primary keys, and making sure that they do not collide.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to limit the length of `UUIDField`. The whole point of `UUIDField` is to generate a unique universal identifier which has no chance that it will generate another `UUID` having the same value as an existing one.

If you want to truncate the length, you can do that but it might lead to collisions and you would get 2 same `ids` which you certainly don't want.

UUID takes multiple parameters into consideration when generating a random number, so using `UUIDField`, you don't need to worry about ever `ids` being generated same.

> UUID values are 128 bits long and “can guarantee uniqueness across
>   space and time”.